# jquery validation plugin not working in modalbox

Tags: jquery

i am trying to validate fields in modalbox however its not working below is my validation code

```
$("#formapplication").validate({
rules: {
        tb_name:{ required: true },
        tb_url: {required: true},
        tb_tag: {required: true},
        tb_desc: {required: true},
        tb_catg: {required: true}
        },
messages:{
        tb_name:{ required: "Please Enter Full name" },
        tb_url: {required: "Please Enter URL"},
        tb_tag: {required: "Please Enter Tag."},
        tb_desc: {required: "Please Enter Description."},
        tb_catg: {required: "Please Select Category."}
        }
    });
```

jquery validation plugin support modalbox but its simple html i write on same page not calling using ajax any idea pelase help.

below is xhtml

```
<div id="submitapplication" style="display:none">
<form action="" id="formapplication" name="formapplication" method="post">
<div class="submitapplicationbox">
<label>Name<input type="text" name="tb_name" id="tb_name" /></label>
<label>Url<input type="text" name="tb_url" id="tb_url" /></label>
<label>Tags<input type="text" name="tb_tag" id="tb_tag" /></label>
<label>Category<select name="select" id="tb_catg">
  <option value=""></option>
  </select></label>
<label>Description
<textarea cols="" rows="" name="tb_desc" id="tb_desc" ></textarea></label>
</div>
<div class="twiteraccountinfobox">
<label>Name<input type="text" name="tb_twaccount" id="tb_twaccount" /></label>
<div style="margin-top:20px;"><input type="button" id="submitapp" value="Submit Application" /></div>
<div id="response" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but one thing's not exactly right here: enclose your field names in quotes; objects in JS should define their members in quotes: {"tb_name": ...}. That surely won't solve your problem but it's a good thing to keep in mind when you create objects in JS.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code - it matches that given by the valdiation documentation fine. Perhaps if you provided your markup too so I could throw together a test page I could help a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

i was missting class required on all my inputs that i am using for validation

```
<input type="text" id="tb_name" class="required" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, first off, add a # to your form action so it's `form action="#"`. The # doesn't fix it, but I have run into IE issues before without a hash in forms.

Also, try adding a line underneath your validation:

```
$("#formapplication").valid();
```

Comment: Thanks Steerpike acutally i was missing class required on all my input

Comment: That's perculiar, as between your methodology and the documentation I had presumed that was intended behaviour. I assumed you were using the 'rules' option to bypass the class required

Comment: how i can use rules to bypass the class required ? would you please tell me i don't know i did't change rules but add required class to markup n it start woriking

Answer (score 0):

1. First, as Seb said, you need quotes around your field names.
2. Second, as I understand the rules and messages hashes from the documentation, you need to refer to elements by the the **name** attribute, not the **id** attribute. So instead of 
   `"tb_catg": {required: true}` I think you want `"select": {required: true}` since your HTML says `<select name="select" id="tb_catg">`